# Why is "this" the global / window object in this case?

Tags: javascript, this

Relatively new to JavaScript here so any help / explanation would be appreciated.

I have the following toy code example and am struggling to explain to myself why I am getting such an output.

```
const list = [1, 2];
let newlist = list.map(function (num){
   console.log(this);     // logs the global / window object in the console
   return num * 2;
});
```

The console.log(this) statement inside the callback function logs the global or the window object in the console. I have gone through this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the map() method of the Array prototype and it states that the map() method has a second argument, ***thisArg***. It further say, ***"If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be used as callback's this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value"***.

I have not provided any value for the ***thisArg*** parameter, so according to the doc, I was expecting the console.log() statement to print out an ***undefined***. So the question is, why is the "this" pointing to the global object in the example code above?

Comment: Because that's how `.map()` works. If you want to pass something else as `this` give it as the third argument to `.map()`. Oh, and it also depends on whether you're in "strict" mode.

Comment: You need to read one more sentence from the docs: "*The `this` value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the `this` seen by a function.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser, call any anonymous function:

```
(function(){
    console.log(this === window); //true
}())
```

So you know that by default, this points to the window object. UNLESS, you pass something else, via calling as a method, from prototype, `call`, `apply` etc. Now go look at the map polyfill:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Here the crux is this line:

```
callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
```

Be careful, T is your thisArg if and only if `arguments.length > 1`, otherwise it is left `undefined`. And guess what, from MDN `Function.prototype.call`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

`.call` method replaces undefined with `global` (window):

```
function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

> **thisArg**
>
> Optional. The value of this provided for the call to a function. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode , null and undefined will be replaced with the global object and primitive values will be converted to objects.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer and for showing the chain of events. This was the kind of answer I was looking for. Very difficult to understand whats going on without going into the internals. Appreciate your help.